# django orm search with postgres

Tags: python, django, django-models, full-text-search, django-orm

For small searches in PostgreSQL, http://django-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orm-pg-fulltext.html can be used easily, as shown in the docs.

Following are the steps, I used to implement it -

```
'''call the libraries'''
from djorm_pgfulltext.models import SearchManager
from djorm_pgfulltext.fields import VectorField


class Notes(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField()
   description = models.TextField()

    # create a vector field
    search_index = VectorField()

    objects = models.Manager()
    search_manager = SearchManager(
        fields=('title', 'description'),
        config='pg_catalog.english',
        search_field='search_index',
        auto_update_search_field=True
    )
```

Ran the migration, and all the changes are being reflected in the database. 
Last step - 
In my postgresql database, I did the following -

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres // login as root

CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
ALTER FUNCTION unaccent(text) IMMUTABLE;
```

All this done, now I open my shell

```
from myapp.models import Notes
  In [2]: Note.search_manager.search("p")
  Out[3]: []
```

Any idea, why I am getting no result??

What is missing?

Comment: Could it be the data in the database? Or you have data already which contains p?

Comment: no i do not get any result for any other key word as well.

Comment: You come from migration. Have you tried to update indexes: `for x in Notes.objects.all(): x._orm_manager.update_index(pk=x.pk) `?

Comment: PostgreSQL full-text search by words not characters.

Comment: @danihp as mentioned auto update is marked true.

Comment: @user1629366, you talk about migration, I doubted if migration was been make with external tool. Regards.